# Example of polynomial in dynamics

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

I am looking for an example of a post-critically finite polynomial $P$ (i.e. all critical points have finite orbit), which has both the following:

- a critical point on its Julia set (such as the polynomial $z^2+i$)
- a super-attracting cycle, other than $\infty$, i.e. a periodic orbit $z_0\mapsto z_1\mapsto \cdots\mapsto z_{n-1} \mapsto z_0$ such that at least one $z_i$ is a critical point (such as the polynomial $z^2-1$ that has a $2$-cycle $0\mapsto -1\mapsto 0$)

Is there some known example from the multibrot families $z^q+c$ or any other example?

How about a post-critically finite polynomial with two critical points on the Julia set?

Comment: You can rule out the mulitbrot family, since they all have a single critical point, namely the origin.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Surely they have two critical points, $0$ and $\infty$?

Comment: @mdave16 Yes, definitely - when viewed as a dynamical system on the Riemann sphere, $\infty$ is a a critical point of any polynomial. Even if we restrict to just the complex plane, it is often useful to think of the point at $\infty$ as a super-attractive fixed point. It is also often useful, though, to distinguish the point at $\infty$ somewhat. In the question at hand, it is specifically stated that *all critical points should have finite orbits*. That immediately rules out the possibility that we consider $\infty$ to be a critical point. And thanks for the wake up call! :)

Comment: No problem about the wake up call, it's how we all get better. -- Why should we not consider $\infty$? as a critical point if all critical points should have finite orbit? Is it because $\infty \mapsto \infty$ has the most dull forward orbit possible? And so it's just a problem to forget it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial $2z^3-3z^2+\dfrac{1}{2}$ has the desired properties.  The critical points are at 0 and 1, with
$$
0\mapsto \frac12 \mapsto 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad 1\mapsto -\frac12 \mapsto -\frac12.
$$
The point $1$ lies on the Julia set itself.  The following picture shows the filled Julia set for this function, with the two critical orbits marked in yellow and red, respectively.

[image]

To find this example, I first decided to look for a cubic polynomial with one critical point of period two and one critical point that maps to a fixed point.  I also decided (without loss of generality) that the critical points should be at $0$ and $1$, so the polynomial should have the form $f(z) = 2az^3-3az^2 + b$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.  I then looked for values of $a$ and $b$ that satisfy the two equations $f(f(0))=0$ and $f(f(1)) = f(1)$.

As for having two critical points on the Julia set, the third [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $4z^3-3z$ has the line segment $[-1,1]$ on the real axis as its Julia set, and its two critical points are $\pm\dfrac12$.

Comment: Very nice!  It might be worth pointing out that it's easy to show that $1$ is in the Julia set using the characterization that the Julia set is the closure of the repelling fixed points. First, $-1/2$ is in the Julia set since it's a repulsive fixed point (i.e. a point of period $1$). Then, $1$ is in the Julia set since it's the inverse image of $-1/2$ and the Julia set is backward invariant.

Comment: Very nice answer! What software are you using for the picture?

Comment: @DimitriosNt It was made in *Mathematica* using code that I wrote myself.  You can find my general Julia set code in the `ColoredJuliaSets.nb` file on [my code web page](http://math.bard.edu/belk/code.htm).

Comment: @JimBelk Have you noticed this in V10: `JuliaSetPlot[2 z^3 - 3 z^2 + 1/2, z]`?

Comment: @MarkMcClure I don't have V10 yet, but that's nice to hear!